# eclipse plug-in dependencies and classnotfoundexception

Tags: eclipse, plugins, dependencies, classnotfound

I am new to Eclipse RCP plugin development and I have the following problem:  I am trying to instantiate a MessageConsole object in my plugin.  I create the appropriate dependency for org.eclipse.ui.console in MANIFEST.MF, build the plugin, and then load the plugin inside the same Eclipse application (I export the plugin as a zip, shutdown Eclipse, unzip and copy the plugin into Eclipse's plugin directory, restart Eclipse).  I get a NoClassDefFoundError when that plugin is loaded.  If I uncomment the single source code line (see below) that tries to instantiate a MessageConsole, the plugin works fine.  Details are as follows.

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: IntrospectorPlugin Plug-in
Bundle-SymbolicName: IntrospectorPlugin; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.1
Bundle-Activator: introspectorplugin.Activator
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.ui.console
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
```

IntrospectorView.java:

```
import org.eclipse.ui.console.ConsolePlugin;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.IConsole;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.IConsoleConstants;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.IConsoleView;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.MessageConsole;
import org.eclipse.ui.console.MessageConsoleStream;
...
     MessageConsole myConsole = new MessageConsole("IntrospectorView plugin console",
        imageDescriptorConsole);
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.ui.console.MessageConsole
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:483)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:399)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:87)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    at introspectorplugin.views.IntrospectorView.makeConsole(IntrospectorView.java:453)
    at introspectorplugin.views.IntrospectorView.createPartControl(IntrospectorView.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPartHelper(ViewReference.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewReference.createPart(ViewReference.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:594)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartPane.setVisible(PartPane.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ViewPane.setVisible(ViewPane.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.PresentablePart.setVisible(PresentablePart.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.PresentablePartFolder.select(PresentablePartFolder.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.LeftToRightTabOrder.select(LeftToRightTabOrder.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.presentations.util.TabbedStackPresentation.selectPart(TabbedStackPresentation.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.refreshPresentationSelection(PartStack.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.createControl(PartStack.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartStack.createControl(PartStack.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PartSashContainer.createControl(PartSashContainer.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PerspectiveHelper.activate(PerspectiveHelper.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Perspective.onActivate(Perspective.java:968)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.onActivate(WorkbenchPage.java:2593)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$25.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2873)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.setActivePage(WorkbenchWindow.java:2854)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$19.runWithException(WorkbenchWindow.java:2171)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3800)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3425)
    at org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor.openWindows(WorkbenchAdvisor.java:803)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$27.runWithException(Workbench.java:1363)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.StartupThreading$StartupRunnable.run(StartupThreading.java:31)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3800)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3425)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2295)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2200)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:495)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:549)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:504)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1236)
```

I looked through my Plugins book which talks about making sure that compile-time dependencies much target run-time dependencies -- if I run the plugin in the same Eclipse executable that I build, I should not have this issue?  Furthermore, I've descended down the plug-in dependencies tree and verified I have all necessary plugins.

All help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed a newer version of Eclipse today, added my plugin into the plugins directory and everything works well.  Obviously I've encountered some configuration issue or a quirk.  My previous version was Ganymede and now I'm running Galileo.

Comment: damn - I have a similar problem, but I'm already running Galileo... Classloaderhell.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and compare your implementation with other example and projects including a Console view, like:

- [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg24449.html) (and its attached zip)
- this [Java Platform Logging Support](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpls/)

In both case, check their dependencies (`plugin.xml` or the `MANIFEST.MF`) in order to see what the difference is, hopefully explaining why your plugin does not include the relevant classes.

Comment: Thanks for you help VonC.  I was able to resolve the problem simply by installing a new version of Eclipse.  Not very encouraging but it works.  I followed your links and compared my plugin configuration files -- they were nearly identical.